# How can I install or test office js add-in on Outlook 2013

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-store

An office-js submission was failed on Outlook 2013 on Windows 7. From what I saw on Outlook 2013, only COM add-ins were possible to install. How can I install or test an add-in by providing the .xml file from my local computer or from the network?

In addition, is it possible to specify in the .xml manifest file of the add-in that I do not want that this add-in be run on Outlook 2013 for example, or must an add-in support all Outlook versions, on all operating systems/browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Web add-ins are supported in Outlook 2013, [how to sideload an add-in in Outlook on the desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing#sideload-an-add-in-in-outlook-on-the-desktop)

No, manifest xml does not control whether an add-in is available for a particular version of Outlook.

Yes, an add-in submitted to AppSource is expected to work in all [supported Outlook clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#outlook-client-support).

Comment: Doesn't work. There is no Get Add-Ins button. I read that sometimes Outlook 2013 doesn't have this button, but has the Store button. I tried to add the Store button, via customizing the ribbon. Then I saw the button, but it is greyed-out. Then I read that sometimes it is greyed out when you use pop3/imap accounts, so I created an account at XXX@outlook.com and added it to the outlook 2013, but then the Store button is still greyed out. Only after I removed the pop/imap account the button suddenly works (i think you have  a bug). But - I don't see the option to add .xml file to the My add-ins.

Comment: Add-ins are not supported on pop3/imap accounts. If you have multiple accounts on a single Outlook 2013 profile, then the button is only available when on messages/appointments that are on an exchange account that supports Exchange. (xxx@Outlook.com should support it). Can you show a screenshot of the UI that doens't allow you to sideload the add-in? You can also install the add-in from OWA and that will also install your add-in on Native clients as well.

Comment: (1) Screenshot of how it looks in Outlook 2013 (same in two different computers): https://ibb.co/9s4HBnd  - as you can see, no option to add an addin from an xml file :(  (2) Regarding OWA, if you mean https://outlook.live.com - then I already did it, it works there, but it doesn't make it appear in the Outlook 2013 software :(

Comment: From your screenshot, it appears that there's no way to install the add-in via Outlook 2013. If you were able to install the add-in successfully in OWA, it should show up in Outlook 2013 depending on the ExtensionPoints and the requirement set specified in the manifest.

Comment: Your add-in does not have to support all Outlook versions. If you want to exempt Office 2013, you can specify the MinVersion of your Requirements set to 1.5, in the VersionOverride 1.0 section of your manifest. For further details, see the section titled "Requirements" on this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/manifests. Please note that specifying 1.5 will also exempt your add-in from showing up in Outlook 2016 MSI. However, it will show up in Outlook 2016 C2R versions.